# SQL SERVER: Count data with the same group using Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

Based on the picture above, I need to come up with the CountRemarks Column where in it will count the number of similar data in Remarks column PER LOCATION. So, Tenant 1 and 2 have total of 2 in Location "EM" and total of 1 only for tenant 3 in the same location. Same counting for Location "CW".

Unfortunately, I have come up to this output, counting all with the same remnarks and DISREGARDING the Location.

[image]

This is the portion in the code that I used

```
 CASE
        WHEN [Remarks]  >= 4 THEN Remarks 
        ELSE count(Remarks) OVER(PARTITION BY [Remarks] )
END as 'CountRemark'
```

Comment: have you tried OVER(PARTITION BY Location) ?

Comment: Yes, it counted the total number of same location found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a window function and partition by Location and Remarks:

```
SELECT 
 Location, Tenant, Remarks, 
 CountRemarks = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Location, Remarks)
FROM your_table
ORDER BY Tenant
```

Given your sample data this results in:

```
Location    Tenant  Remarks CountRemarks
EM          Tenant1 1       2
EM          Tenant2 1       2
EM          Tenant3 2       1
CW          Tenant4 1       2
CW          Tenant5 1       2
CW          Tenant6 2       1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select location,tenant,remarks,count(*) over (partition by Location,remarks) as 
counterremarks from table
```

Comment: No, still the same output, counting all Remarks with the same data and DISREGARDING the per location counting

Comment: Then you also need location in the partition clause. Refer my edited reply